# How to access Google Analytics in django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools

I have a doubt how to google analytics dispaly in django admin panel.can give any suggestion or give proper documentation.I see many documentation cant understand .can give any example code.I tried but its not working can give proper documentation or any code.I tried api key also is not working .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-google-analytics-app](https://pypi.org/project/django-google-analytics-app/) and then create custom page in your admin panel. There are few tutorials on how to do this even on Stack.